# Combining Devise with resources :users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to combine Devise with a RESTful user resource using the following code in the routes.rb file:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]
devise_for :users
```

However the url localhost:3000/users/sign_up does not go to the devise sign up page, rather it produces the error "Couldn't find User with ID=sign_up", so it thinks the url is pointing to the show action of the users controller. 
I have found that swapping the order of the lines produces the intended behaviour:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Now when you go to localhost:3000/users/sign_up you do indeed get the sign-up page, and going to localhost:3000/users/1 hits the show action of the users controller as intended.

My question is this: is changing the code order like this the correct way to get devise working together with the users resource? Or is there something deeper going wrong? I suspect that merely swapping those two lines of code round can't be the solution!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My advice in these situations is to check with `rake routes`
In routes the order in which routes are defined matters since earlier routes take precedence.

So in your case `resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]` created a restfull `/users/:id(.:format)` route that pointed to `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}`
and when you went to Devise's sign up url `/users/sign-up` it considered 'sign-up' an `:id` of the user and naturally couldnt find it.

Now if you do the devise routing setup first, devise's routes take precedence over anything specified later and you get expected behaviour.

Comment: I still get the same error, even I wrote the devise before the resource. Do you have any idea why? thx

Answer (score 16):

Yes, that's the right way to do it (see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)

Answer (score 3):

In the link David Sulc wrote is shown that you should write a prefix to [**device_for** or **resources**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)
Example:

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'my'
resources :users
```

Or your users

```
devise_for :users
scope "/admin" do
  resources :users
end
```

Both works well for me

Comment: You should include the link in your answer.