# Ruby on Rails - NameError: uninitialized constant UsersController at /admin/users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've added the users resource under admin to allow admin to control/modify user accounts.  But I'm getting an error about **uninitialized constant UsersController**.  User accounts are handled by devise.  Currently I just want to create the index page to list each user.  Here are the parts that are relevant:

`/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

I've made sure to have my devise_for :users at the start of my routes.

`/conig/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  scope "/admin" do
    resources :users
  end

  root :to => "visitors#index"
end
```

I know the view isn't the problem.  The page I'm trying to load displays this error.

[image: Rails Error Output]

Other than that everything else works fine.  Do I need to have the UsersController handled differently?  For instance do I need to inherit from a Devise controller?

Comment: I'd be easier to just make a regular admin controller file: /app/controllers/admin_controller.rb  This question might be helpful if you want to continue with your current approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051487/combining-devise-with-resources-users-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope` assumes you're going to put your controllers in a namespace (so with scope it would just be `UsersController` not `Admin::UsersController`, and no /admin directory). If you want to use an `Admin` namespace/directory, you need to define your route like this:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
  end
```

As an aside, you can see what your routes are pointing to with `rake routes`. Try running it with `scope` vs `namespace` and you'll see how it changes things.

Comment: Thank you!  That wasn't explained in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface so I'm glad you explained it.